# Angular ngrx Effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Using ngrx, if I dispatch an action which attempts to set the state of the store to the value already contained in the store, then obviously there is no change to the state.

However, any effects waiting on that action are still invoked. Is there a standard way to prevent the effect from running if the action has resulted in no change?

Answer (score 0):

In the effect for this action, you can add concatLatestFrom with a selector to get the latest value you are interested in from the store.It will be already updated from the reducer there. Then add a filter to compare the action body and this value the way you want. The filter with the appropriate check will stop the action from further processing.

e.g

```
ofType(ProductDetailPage.loaded),
concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(selectProducts)),
filter(([{ payload }, products]) => !!products[payload.sku])
```

The sample above is from [this post](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this) with best practices for ngrx effects.